# Redis usecase for social auth data

Tags: node.js, redis, everyauth

I checked EveryAuth module which has excellent features and decided to use in my project.

My Question is, How to handle the social auth data (twitter,facebook...) in redis

Comment: What is your question? Do you need a data layout?

Answer (score 1):

As redis is a key-value system, you need to create your keys accordingly.

For example, you might do this :

```
set user:1:name first_user
set username:first_user:id 1
```

Then for the data itself

```
set user:1:email myemail@whatever.com
set user:1:twitter_auth whatever"
set user:1:facebook_auth whatever
```

There is no specific way to do it, but if you need relationship between keys, you need to handle it yourself ( such a username<->id relationship shown above )

Comment: Thanks @crazyjul... which one is good as primarykey email or social auth id